# how to know whats missing in info.plist before uploading the build?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I work for various clients. Whenever i upload a build i forget to add privacy or some other keys into info.plist. which leads to an email sent to my client about the missing item. This get embarrassing some times.
What i am doing right now is to add myself in testflight so that i can get notified as well but that doens't save me from letting clients know. 
So how can i be certain that i am not missing anything. is there some test environment or something which can tell me about missing items?

Comment: Best practice is to have a list with needed permissions (key and explain text) sepparate, then add what you need in info.plist.

Comment: just test your app before shipping it? The debugger in Xcode will tell you when you didn't include something in your info.plist

Answer (score 1):

Try validate your binary before upload. It is available in the Organizer bellow the distribution option in the same place that you probably use to upload:
[image]